# switch to workspaces by clicking on workspaces' thumbnails in activity overview without selecting a window

Tags: gnome, workspaces

How can I switch to workspace by clicking on workspaces' thumbnails in activity overview without selecting a window.

I mean, When I use keybinding for `Move to workspace on the left / right`, it just move to the workspace. But when I click on the workspaces' thumbnails in activity overview it **wait till I select a window**. I do not want that. I want to move to the workspace immediately after clicking on the thumbnail. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just double-click one of the tiny desktop icons on the top. One click selects it without selecting a specific window, a second click "zooms in".

Using the large "zoomed out" representation of the desktop, click once to select the workspace, then click on free background to "zoom in". This way, the window that was focused before you switched workspaces remains in focus.

Comment: So, basically i have to double click. That is ok for me, however an option of settings or extension for single click would be great.

Comment: Indeed, it is double-click: once to select, then to go to. You can also use the tiny icons on top - then you never will select a specific window - actually, I was about to add that to my answer.

Comment: i have custom keybinding `super+ctrl+left/right` to switch workspace. I can also change workspace by scrolling on the taskbar (Dash to Panel). But somethimes I do not remember which workspace I was look for. In this (double click) solution, i can see and then move to a workspace using mouse.

Comment: Yes, the keyboard is usually faster, but sometimes having the overview first come in handy. Yet, you still can use the keyboard for selection using the overview also: Super, PgDn/PdUp until you selected the desired workspace, then Esc

Answer (score 0):

Install `Workspace Indicator` Gnome Shell Extension which performs that function by putting an indicator on the panel signalling in which workspace you are currently in giving you the possibility of switching to another one.

[image]